# extract from pcap all protocols found

Tags: network, tools, protocols, sniffer

I have some pcap files, and i would like just to get a list of protocols that are present on that pcap file. I would like it in a batch mode, not using **wireshark**

I think **tshark** is able to do it, but i couldn't find how. any idea?

Comment: this might be a cool site to track to help with pcap analyses http://www.pcapr.net/xtractr/

Comment: yes i love pcapr but it is for a internal project, i cannot use them :-/

Comment: Xplico can be used to that goal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that `-Tfields -eframe.protocols` would be the closest thing you'll get.
The output looks something like this:

```
eth:ip:tcp:http
eth:ip:tcp
eth:ip:tcp:http:media
eth:ip:tcp
eth:ip:udp:nbdgm:smb:browser
eth:ip:tcp
eth:arp
eth:arp
eth:ipv6:udp:http
eth:ip:udp:http
```

As it can be seen the information displayed will vary a bit depending on which protocol dissector gets to play. So you'll need to do some post-processing to cut the parts you don't need and/or dedup (for instance using @Mark's suggestion in the comment).

Comment: I'd +1 if I had any votes left for the day. Might want to do tshark -r test.cap -Tfields -eframe.protocols | sort | uniq so you only get a list uniq entries.

Comment: i think i will choose this one. i liked the tcpdstat, and i think i will use it, but since my question was about the tshark, i think this result is the best, for my needs, using tshark.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried `tshark -r test.cap -q -z io,phs`

It will give you a hierarchical list of protocols, not sure if it will suite you needs.

```
===================================================================
Protocol Hierarchy Statistics
Filter: frame

frame                                    frames:433 bytes:290520
  eth                                    frames:433 bytes:290520
    ip                                   frames:433 bytes:290520
      tcp                                frames:423 bytes:289464
        http                             frames:188 bytes:267285
        ssh                              frames:24 bytes:7968
        ssl                              frames:2 bytes:237
      udp                                frames:10 bytes:1056
        data                             frames:6 bytes:355
        ntp                              frames:2 bytes:180
        nbdgm                            frames:2 bytes:521
          smb                            frames:2 bytes:521
            mailslot                     frames:2 bytes:521
              browser                    frames:2 bytes:521
===================================================================
```

To get just the list of protocols you could do some commandline KungFu.

`tshark -r test.cap -z io,phs -q | tr -s ' ' | cut -f 2 -d ' ' | tail -n +7 | head -n -1`

which will give you

```
eth
ip
tcp
http
ssh
ssl
udp
data
ntp
nbdgm
smb
mailslot
browser
```

Answer (score 3):

[tcpdstat](http://staff.washington.edu/dittrich/talks/core02/tools/tools.html) will do this for you. I believe it's mentioned in one of Richard Bejtlich's books.

Comment: i will check it. looks good.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike most other tools, [Bro](http://www.bro-ids.org) detects application protocols in a *port-agnostic* fashion. For example, it detects HTTP not on just the standard ports (80, 8080, etc.), but in *any* TCP connection.

Extracting the number of connections (TCP and UDP) is straight-forward:

```
bro -r trace.pcap
bro-cut service < conn.log | sort | uniq -c
```

Example output from a small HTTP trace:

```
 19 -
 53 dns
 34 http
```